# Can you use DocumentViewer to show single pages at a time?

Tags: c#, wpf, documentviewer

I am trying to show an XPS file one page at a time then using a timer changing pages, the problem is that when I use the `FitToHeight` method, it shows more than just that one page, about one and a half pages. I am not sure how to go about changing the viewing size of a DocumentViewer.

This is the code I use to retrieve the XPS file. (PowerPoint slides printed to an XPS format)

```
XpsDocument xpsDoc = new XpsDocument(
    System.IO.Path.Combine(
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "DemoDeck.xps"),
    FileAccess.Read);
myDocumentViewer.Document = xpsDoc.GetFixedDocumentSequence();
```

This is the XAML for my DocumentViewer.

```
<DocumentViewer x:Name="myDocumentViewer" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
    VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" 
    VerticalContentAlignment="Center" MaxPagesAcross="1" Zoom="100">
    <DocumentViewer.Resources>
        <!-- Hides the search box-->
        <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
        </Style>
        <!-- Hides the toolbar -->
        <Style TargetType="ToolBar">
    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="ScrollViewer">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Hidden"/>
        </Style>
    </DocumentViewer.Resources>
</DocumentViewer>
```